# Excluding .java from a jar present in a WAR

Tags: maven, jar, war

I got two maven projects, P1 requires P2's java-sources at compile time. So, I have included sources in the P2's jar, to be included as dependency in P1's pom. How do I exclude those .java files from final war creation?

Or, is there a better way to package P1's jar?

Comment: Why does p1 requires P2's java sources?

Comment: P1 is client code on GWT. P2 is Spring. I don know much detail. My task just is to convert these java projects to maven projects. If I only include .class then it throws error: sources not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would be to create and deploy a separate JAR with sources for P2 and add this as a dependency for the GWT compile in P1.

For the sources JAR have a look at the [maven-sources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-mojo.html).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>attach-sources</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

If you add this in the build section of your POM, the build will create a separate JAR with the classifier 'sources'.

You can then add this artifact to the maven GWT compiler plugin as dependency:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <compileSourcesArtifacts>
      <compileSourcesArtifact>your.groupId:artifactId</compileSourcesArtifact>
    </compileSourcesArtifacts>
  </plugin>
```